# Mypy unable to analyse types of tuple elements in a list comprehension

Tags: python

All presented code samples were tested with Python 3.11, and mypy 1.6.0

And the problem is: mypy sees no problems in the following code:

```
MyTupleType = tuple[int, str, bool]
Tuples = list[MyTupleType]
 
def findAllByInt(values : Tuples, ref : int) -> Tuples:
  return [v for v in values if v[1] == ref]  # here is the bug!
 
vals : Tuples = [ (1, 'a', True), (2, 'b', False),
                  (3, 'c', True), (1, 'd', False) ]
 
print( findAllByInt(vals, 1) )
```

Problem is the tuple element index, which is compared to the referenced value. The element index should be 0, not 1. v[1] is a str, while v[0] is an int.

The only solution I was able to achieve is to use a separate function to extract the tuple element:

```
MyTupleType = tuple[int, str, bool]
Tuples = list[MyTupleType]
 
def intOfMyTuple(t : MyTupleType) -> int:
  return t[0]
 
def findAllByInt(values : Tuples, ref : int) -> Tuples:
  return [v for v in values if intOfMyTuple(v) == ref]
 
vals : Tuples = [ (1, 'a', True), (2, 'b', False),
                  (3, 'c', True), (1, 'd', False) ]
 
print( findAllByInt(vals, 1) )
```

Now, when we change the element index in intOfMyTuple, mypy will complain about the type mismatch, which is exactly what mypy should do.

Is it really neccessary to write separate functions for each tuple and element index I use in my code?

I'm doing something wrong, and mypy can be used to properly check the types in the first code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of problem is in the return line of `findAllByInt` function:

```
def findAllByInt(values : Tuples, ref : int) -> Tuples:
  return [v for v in values if v[1] == ref]
```

More precisely: the comparison v[1] == ref. The point is, this comparison is fine: there's nothing wrong with comparing apples to oranges. Of course, such comparisons will always be negative, since apples are not oranges (and in Python: ints are not strs).

The solution is to use `--strict-equality mypy option`